# Building VirtualBox With Emscripten throws error: 'kmk: *** Exiting with status 2 emmake: error: 'kmk -p all' failed (returned 2)'

Tags: c, virtualbox, emscripten, kbuild

I am trying to build VirtualBox through Emscripten, and I have been mostly successful in solving the issues that come with attempting to do so(Quite a few), but I cannot figure this one out. I am building on a Debian distribution, if that helps.

```
/workspace/Ruffle-Embedded/Vbox/out/linux.amd64/release/bin/src/vboxnetflt/include/iprt/utf16.h: /workspace/Ruffle-Embedded/Vbox/include/iprt/utf16.h | /workspace/Ruffle-Embedded/Vbox/out/linux.amd64/release/bin/src/vboxnetflt/include/iprt/
#  Implicit rule search has not been done.
#  Modification time never checked.
#  File has not been updated.
#  recipe to execute (from '/workspace/Ruffle-Embedded/Vbox/kBuild/footer-pass2-installs.kmk', line 67):
        %$(call MSG_INST_FILE,/workspace/Ruffle-Embedded/Vbox/include/iprt/utf16.h,/workspace/Ruffle-Embedded/Vbox/out/linux.amd64/release/bin/src/vboxnetflt/include/iprt/utf16.h)

        $(QUIET)$(INSTALL_STAGING)   -m a+r,u+w                -- /workspace/Ruffle-Embedded/Vbox/include/iprt/utf16.h /workspace/Ruffle-Embedded/Vbox/out/linux.amd64/release/bin/src/vboxnetflt/include/iprt/utf16.h


# files hash-table stats:
# Load=29948/32768=91%, Rehash=0, 
# VPATH Search Paths

# No 'vpath' search paths.

# No general ('VPATH' variable) search path.

# kBuild defines

# strcache2: file
#  5 segments: total = 5242560 / max = 1048528 / avg = 1048512 / def = 1048576  avail = 770944
#  39818 strings: total len = 2468646 / max = 196 / avg = 61 / min = 1
#  hash size = 131072  mask = 0x1ffff  rehashed 0 times
#  hash insert collisions = 5501 (13%)
#  96755 (73%) empty hash table slots
#  29343 (22%) occupied hash table slots
#   4485 (13%) with 1 string  chained on;  4974 (12%) strings at depth 1.
#    453 ( 1%) with 2 strings chained on;   489 ( 1%) strings at depth 2.
#     34 ( 0%) with 3 strings chained on;    36 ( 0%) strings at depth 3.
#      2 ( 0%) with 4 strings chained on;     2 ( 0%) strings at depth 4.

# strcache2: variable
#  4 segments: total = 4194096 / max = 1048528 / avg = 1048524 / def = 1048576  avail = 116912
#  50282 strings: total len = 1675549 / max = 160 / avg = 33 / min = 1
#  hash size = 262144  mask = 0x3ffff  rehashed 0 times
#  hash insert collisions = 4531 (9%)
#  216393 (82%) empty hash table slots
#  41509 (15%) occupied hash table slots
#   3974 ( 8%) with 1 string  chained on;  4242 ( 8%) strings at depth 1.
#    249 ( 0%) with 2 strings chained on;   268 ( 0%) strings at depth 2.
#     17 ( 0%) with 3 strings chained on;    19 ( 0%) strings at depth 3.
#      2 ( 0%) with 4 strings chained on;     2 ( 0%) strings at depth 4.


# Alloc Cache: incdep rec
#  Items: size = 64   total = 39897 

# Alloc Cache: dirfile
#  Items: size = 32   total = 10235 

# Alloc Cache: directory_contents
#  Items: size = 128  total = 511   

# Alloc Cache: directories
#  Items: size = 16   total = 4094  

# Alloc Cache: variable_set_list
#  Items: size = 32   total = 12282 

# Alloc Cache: variable_set
#  Items: size = 128  total = 10731 

# Alloc Cache: variable
#  Items: size = 96   total = 100254

# Alloc Cache: commands
#  Items: size = 64   total = 14322 

# Alloc Cache: file
#  Items: size = 192  total = 30690 

# Alloc Cache: nameseq
#  Items: size = 16   total = 8188  

# Alloc Cache: goaldep
#  Items: size = 64   total = 1023  

# Alloc Cache: dep
#  Items: size = 64   total = 337590

# Finished Make data base on Thu Mar 21 13:36:15 2024

kmk: *** Exiting with status 2
emmake: error: 'kmk -p all' failed (returned 2)
```

This is what I get when executing

```
cd Vbox
source ./env.sh
../emsdk/upstream/emscripten/emmake kmk -p all
```

I have searched everywhere, nothing seems to cover what I'm trying to do here, and what this generic error message means.

Thank you all in advance,

Jacob

Comment: Perhaps some rude questions ... AFAICT, `emscripten` is for building webassembly apps. VirtualBox is a VM _hypervisor_. It's been a while since I've built VirtualBox. But, IIRC, it needs root access to install a kernel device driver (and needs the bios to enable VT-x et. al.). And, root to start it up? I'm not sure you can do these things under webassembly. Are you _just_ trying to build and install VirtualBox under debian? If so, just use the normal VirtualBox build tools. What are your end goal(s)? Otherwise, is this an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/785231)?

Comment: I am aware of this, I am going to host the code on a service that provides a Debian distribution, kernel included, and this will run alongside Webassembly. I am using a portable version of VirtualBox, so I shouldn't need to worry about the drivers or kernel anyway. The end goal is to see if I could port VirtualBox to Wasm, any issues that arise after compilation are a different story, I need a baseline to start with. Also, the questions are not rude, just pointed. I guess the point is to compile and then figure it out afterward.